# Create opportunities in Marketo

Tags: marketo

I want to integrate Marketo api with my .net project.

My client has given a username & password to Marketo. I want to retrieve "opportunities" from Marketo. I have written code for that. Currently there are not any opportunities so I'm not able to test my code. Has anyone an idea how to create opportunities in Marketo so I can whetehr check my code is retrieving that records or not?

Comment: I cleaned up the question, but this really seems a question on how to use Marketo. That is not programming-related, even if you're a programmer.

Comment: Marketo is API and we can call programtically it's method so this question is related to programming.
if you have no idea then you no need to give answer

Answer (score 1):

Opportunities are not visible as standalone entities in Marketo as they are in SFDC or other CRMs. Rather, as @joev said, you have to find a lead that has an opportunity and view the opportunity details within the context of that lead's detail view, on the Opportunity tab.

If you want to use the GUI to create an opportunity, the right place to do that would be in the CRM — not in Marketo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have create/update right via API, ask your client for create/update rights then you will be able to create some data through API itself.

Comment: I want to add opportunities from UI side. I have done code for insert opportunities but I could not see where this opportunity is added in UI and where it will be used.

Comment: It seems rather confusing what you are trying to achieve,  if you want to work through API to  Create/Update and get opportunity object then you can find compleet development istruction here in developer doc.

http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/opportunity-api/describe-opportunity/

Comment: Thanks guys for your reply..
I have right for crate/ update and I can create/update using API.
but my question is from UI side where we can find this created/updated opportunities?

Comment: @user3782833  If you Double Click in lead it will open in new tab with detail information. And you can fine Opportunity Info Tab there.

Answer (score 0):

Like other people have mentioned there isn't a direct GUI inside Marketo for creating opportunities. These are typically created via the CRM (aka Salesforce, NetSuite, Microsoft Dynamics, etc...) and then sync'd to Marketo.

**If** you want to test it and have no CRM available -- technically you can just use the REST API to sync your own opportunity to a lead. Once done you could login to Marketo to visually validate it. Then now that you have an opportunity created you could then use the API to GET the opportunities and further validate your integration.

Here is [a link](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Opportunities/syncOpportunitiesUsingPOST) to Marketo's documentation on how to sync an opportunity to Marketo. Also on that page is the documentation on the other REST API options.